# Projectile - "PATH is not a project"?

Tags: projectile

For some reason, Projectile has stopped allowing me to add new projects.

When I add the project, it seems to work. But when I select the project with `C-c p p` I get the following error:

[image]

Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960037/emacs-projectile-you-are-not-in-a-project-displayed-when-in-directory), they said.

> I think your project is indeed considered a project by projectile only
> if you have a .git folder in it (did you forget to git init?). I'm not
> seeing one in your case. You can alternatively add a .projectile file
> instead. Everything in that folder containing the .projectile file and
> all subfolders will be considered part of the same project.

[edit] to add to this, it must be a git repository with a non-hidden file commited to it. For example a repo that only contained `.file_to_satisfy_projectile` in the git history would not be sufficient, but `file_to_satisfy_projectile` would be.

Comment: This worked. Thank you @hercislife